# How to run TopoJSON?

Tags: node.js, topojson

I need to convert a geojson file to topojson and possibly simplify the topojson file. I've managed to install Node.js and the topojson package. But I have no idea how to run topojson.

The wiki lists a bunch of command line options, but where do I run those commands? I've tried running them both in the command prompt and the node shell. Node, GDAL, ogr2ogr and TopoJSON are all new concepts for me, so I'm a bit confused and overwhelmed.

I'm running on Windows by the way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this should work fine on windows too

1. install nodejs http://nodejs.org/
2. install npm https://npmjs.org/doc/README.html
3. run `npm install -g topojson` in your command prompt
4. use the command prompt to `cd` to the geojson file
5. run `topojson -o myNewTopojsonFile.json myOldGeojsonFile.json`

origin https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45138/convert-geojson-to-topojson

Comment: The first 4 steps works fine. But when using the topojson command, I'm prompted with "topojson is not an internal command...etc".

Comment: I actually gave up on Windows and installed Ubuntu on my laptop :) I'm having problems installing gdal now, but at least topojson is working. Thanks for your help, I'll mark this answer as correct since it probably should work for most users.

Comment: I get through a portion of npm install -g topojson, but it fails with lines such as 
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:43:28)

Comment: @MarjorieRoswell install gyp

Comment: thanks very much Fresheyeball. Went ahead and did that only to continue to get errors. Do I need to add gyp to my path? (it seems to reside in several locations when I do a search for it) I'm still getting that error message, even after doing 'sudo npm install -g gyp' (actually, when I run the topjson command, it complains that d3 is missing, and when I do 'sudo npm install -g d3' I get that gyp error.

Comment: @MarjorieRoswell yeah, it does sound like a path issue.

Comment: Success. I learned that installing Xcode does NOT install Command Line Tools by default. I had to install via Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > Components

I had seen the command line tools displayed at:
Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools
(It  said "Command Line Tools" and displayed a path!) But that didn't mean it was installed, apparently. Now installed, I got through 'npm install -g topojson' successfully.

Comment: @MarjorieRoswell oh yeah. For osx its a requirement to get almost anything done.

Answer (score 31):

`topojson` executable is now changed to `geo2topo`

- Installation steps remain the same, just like `topojson`
- To create a topo json file from geo json file, `geo2topo -o topo-output.json geo-input.json`

One way to obtain `geo-input.json` is from `gdal` which takes a shape file as input and outputs geojson. gdal can be installed via home brew using `brew install gdal`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04.

I found that my node.js executable is called nodejs instead of node.

I opened the topojson script (usr/bin/topojson) and found that it was trying to run topojson with a node executable called node.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

I edited this file so that it runs with nodejs instead

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs
```

and now it works fine for me.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: to do this you can use this command: "ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node"

Comment: saldy i get an error /bin# ReferenceError: Promise is not defined

Answer (score 1):

It has been changed to geo2topo

1) Run

```
sudo npm install -g geo2topo
```

2) check if it returns the path

```
which geo2topo
```

It should give the path `/usr/bin/geo2topo`

3) Use it to convert your geojson file

```
geo2topo -o output.json input.json
```